# File corrupted after uploading on server in GWT

Tags: gwt, file-upload

I'm using `gwtupload.client.MultiUploader` to upload zip files on the server in GWT. Then on the server I transform zip file to array of bytes to insert into database. As the result 50% of files in database are corrupted. Here a little bit of my code.

```
@UiField(provided = true)
MultiUploader muplDef;

public MyClass(){
        muplDef = new MultiUploader();
        muplDef.setValidExtensions("zip");
        muplDef.addOnFinishUploadHandler(onFinishUploaderHandler);
        muplDef.addOnCancelUploadHandler(onCancelUploaderHander);
}

private final IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler onFinishUploaderHandler = new IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler() {
        @SuppressWarnings("incomplete-switch")
        @Override
        public void onFinish(IUploader uploader) {
            switch (uploader.getStatus()) {

            case SUCCESS:
                attachZip = true;
            }
        }
    };
    private final IUploader.OnCancelUploaderHandler onCancelUploaderHander = new IUploader.OnCancelUploaderHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(IUploader uploader) {
            attachZip = false;
        }
    };
```

**Byte Array**

```
String fileName = "D:\1.zip";
                File f = new File(fileName);
                byte[] edocBinary = new byte[(int) f.length()];
                RandomAccessFile ff;
                try {
                    ff = new RandomAccessFile(f, "r");
                    ff.readFully(edocBinary);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

My questions are: Files can be correpted even if I have OnFinishUploaderHandler and case:SUCCESS? There are other cases like ERROR, maybe this case will check the file? Or the problem is with the transformation to byte array? Can you provide me some advices, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you had two steps :

1- Uploading the zip file

2- Inserting the zip file in the database

If the step 1 is done correctly, you're gonna get a success showing that the file is transfered correcly from client to the server, what you do after that is not managed by GwtUpload.

So I guess the corruption happened when you try to insert the file in the database. If you are using MySQL Try this http://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/insert-file-data-into-mysql-database-using-jdbc

Comment: In your link I found the following "BLOB: 65,535 bytes (64 KB)". My table contains BLOB column, but the max size of my zip file is 10MB. Maybe I should use MEDIUMBLOB type?

Comment: Yes MEDIUMBLOB would be fine

Comment: I found out that 100% is the problem in first step. GwtUpload transfers files with error. Maybe the server is very slow. Can you provide me some advices: does gwt check hash of transferring data, or you can give me some info where I can learn more about uploading data in GWT?